# How to get distinct count over multiple columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this. And I want to get the distinct count across the three columns.

| ID | Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C |
| 2 | A | A | B |
| 3 | A | A |  |

The desired output I'm looking for is:

| ID | Column1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | unique_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | 3 |
| 2 | A | A | B | 2 |
| 3 | A | A |  | 1 |

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to run this on Hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `cross apply` for this one.

```
select  *
from    t cross apply 
         (select count(distinct cnt) as unique_count 
          from (values(Column1),(Column2),(Column3)) t(cnt)) t2
```

| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | unique_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | 3 |
| 2 | A | A | B | 2 |
| 3 | A | A |  | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3192ba9ca77783c623c0b57b5617de2c&hide=1)

Comment: This is indeed a viable solution but looks like Hive doesn't have CROSS APPLY

Comment: you didn't mention Hive in your question. Please accept this answer and post a new question and I'll answer it there.

Comment: Thank you! I just added another question.

Answer (score -1):

In standard SQL, you have to UNPIVOT first, do the count(distinct) group by on the PIVOTed result and then PIVOT again.

In recent ORACLE version, you could write your own Polymorphic Table Function to do it, passing the table and the list of columns to count for DISTINCT values.

Answer (score -2):

try if this works

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM TABLENAME);
```